# Shortest Edge Paths between two empties

Tags: modeling, node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

so I'm trying to get the shortest path between two empties using the "Shortest edge paths" node, but I can't figure out how to get the vertex of the mesh where the object is located. I already tried with "Field at Index" and the "Transfer Attribute" node, but that didn't work.

This is the setup I tried with:
[image]

As I understand it, I have to somehow get a matching input in B of the equal node for it to work properly, right?

Can someone please explain what I need to get it correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't watched the whole video yet, but 
Kaizen Tutorials has done a detailed tutorial on using it [here](https://youtu.be/-NOqNMWukl0). It's only available in Blender 3.4 Alpha of course!

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you for your reply! The video is very informative in general and goes in the direction of what I need, but I still can not figure out how to solve the problem of having just a single path between two objects and not multiple as he shows in the video.

Comment: I'm no expert on geometry nodes. Perhaps someone else here can point you in the right direction! I see that Joey Carlino also posted a video on using it [here](https://youtu.be/0MTiMby4NaQ) on the same day. Perhaps that one has more useful info for you.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Oh, I'm a bit late for the party and my approach is very similar to *Crantisz*' answer. It's not a real difference but my solution uses...</sup> Vector Math! ;-) <sup>... maybe it's still helpful for someone.</sup>

This new *Shortest Edge Paths* node can be a bit confusing, especially when there are more than one start and end point involved. I recommend creating a little playground for visualization.

[image: screenshot geometry nodes]

Finding which point is near a given *Empty* object is straightforward. You calculate the distance between the *Empty* and the *Position* of the points that you have. If the distance is zero then it's a perfect match. Due to the limited numerical accuracy of the floating point numbers, the comparision is  exactly with zero but +/- tolerance. This tolerance value is called *Epsilon* for the *Compare (Equal)* node. Finally, in conjunction with the *Vector Math (Distance)* node, it defines a search radius.

Let's put it into a node group because we need it twice, one time for the start empty and another time for the goal empty:

[image: node group "is next to object"]

The node group works like a filter to sort out the mesh vertices that should be used as the start of the shortest paths. It's kinda like a callback in a programming language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use geometry proximity to find the nearest vertexes like this:

[image]