# Attribute as Selection

Tags: geometry-nodes

My goal is to use serial of specific list of numbers as vertex selection.

For example if I have a numbers 1,3,17 and I want to distribute instances on a grid at vertex number 1,3,17.

Since I don't see an option to use String node as source I imported CSV text file via addon. It generates an object and stores values as Attribute per vertex. No problem for Loc/Rot/Scale like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/281079/2214), but what about selection?

I can see the attribute (named vertices) is there ...

[image]

... but attribute is not seen as vertices by Selection socket.

[image]

Ideas how to solve the issue?

[image]

Comment: maybe i misunderstood, but shouldn't be the selection a boolean than an integer? so if they are all > 0 ...they are all true

Comment: Chris is right, since it's a boolean field, it's only looking if they're greater than 0 or not, and they're all positive so it selects all first 7 points. You need to *compare* the sampled index numbers to the context's (grid). However, while that works for me if I sample a single index, it doesn't when I look at all indices so I'm a bit stumped as well: https://i.imgur.com/k1QQrzj.mp4

Comment: @Chris  Thanks for contribution, but I'm and I will be a geonode looser (I do very elementary progress full of pain, so If you want to help just hints are not helping me, sorry ... use answer or screen to illustrate please. Transfer Attribute > Boolean the output is 1 for all.

Comment: @Kuboå Thanks for try ... I can't even try it since at home my Mac can't open last Blender 3.4 based on Metal, so no "Sample Index" node available ...

Comment: Just a few thoughts 1) your "vertices" attribute is actually the indexes of the verts that your want to select/mark. That means you need to compare these numbers with the index of the grid, which results in a boolean value (true/false = selected/not selected). -- 2) The *Transfer Attribute* node loops through all verts of the grid (destination) & adds the attribute of the sources mesh. If there are not enough values it repeats the last value. This means you cannot match the indexes because the *Index* node only gives you the index of the source mesh, not the destination. You need both indexes

Comment: @Blunder ad1 thanks, yes, thats what I understood from Kuboå that he tried and failed  ... I was naive thinking Selections reads just a numbers without comparing real vertex number. ad2) I noticed that in Viewer ... any solution on your mind ... Thanks

Comment: Sample Index is basically the same as Transfer Att. with an Integer inserted into its Index slot: https://i.imgur.com/bYUBjU5.png Here you can see it's correctly working for a single index, but when you leave at just "Index" it stops working. Interestingly, in the old Transfer Att. node it seems to work like @Blunder says, repeating the last value after it runs out of index: https://i.imgur.com/N7tRQJ6.png but it simply gives 0 in the new Sample nodes instead: https://i.imgur.com/H43Ptco.png It still should work for the first 7 points I feel, but it doesn't. I don't know why.

Comment: Last time I was confused about a similar situation I had to ask @quellenform : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes?noredirect=1#comment481949_264857 Maybe he can point to the solution again here.

Comment: Can you point us in the direction of the add-on? I would expect the CSV to be something like  <Index>,<Boolean> \n  for all vertices.. or you (we) could write your (our) own script..

Comment: Here is a very similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/262146/107598 - the answer was to expand the input set and specify for each vert if it is selected or not. It's the same Robin Betts just suggested. It is a working solution (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HMMr.jpg), but very inefficient for a small selection with a large number of vertices. If you select 10 of 1000 vertices you need 10 true and 990 false values. Here is a script that expands the input values (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjAN.jpg). Make sure you have the objects selected before you run it.

Comment: https://github.com/simonbroggi/blender_spreadsheet_import @RobinBetts Sorry ... addon was linked in my answer mentioned in this Q ... Thank you.

Comment: I was just writing a comment to your deleted A :) in short ... Tired now to test it ... I appreciate your attention and help guys ... Robin - CSV or addon doesn't matter, if you know a way how to feed Selection socket by a bunch of numbers referring to vertex index directly copy-paste or blenders Text editor even better. It sounds to interesting topic in general, but the first impuls was Q mentioned in my Q here.

Comment: Hi, @vklidu ! i was doing the washing-up when i realized (doooooooh!) I'd done the whole thing upside-down :) See revision.

Comment: @Blunder even node tree looks simple I would like to avoid additional script in process ... And like in comment to Robin, I don't want to you assign to the CSV or Attribute if you think there is easier way to feed Selection socket by numbers. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I withdraw my question above (why my setup would work with a single index but not the Index node). After finally having had my dinner my brain started working a bit and I realized that the compare ("Equal") node is not saying "get me the points with these index numbers", it's saying "compare this list of numbers with the indices of my points, going down the list one by one, and if they're the same, select them". Single index works because you write the same one value to *all* points so it inevitably finds one that's equal to it. Duh.

Comment: @Kuboå :) Thanks for investigation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sample the grid at the indices in the Named Attribute 'vertices', set the Test Vertices object's vertices to those points, and instance on those:

[image]

with this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ha ... it took me from a bed now! Thanks ... I went by this way at the beginning, but I failed - so close / so far :) Thanks a lot. Before I leave this topic - Am I right with my comment under my Q? There is not any simpler way to feed Selection socket without addon (to generate attribute from CSV) ... like from Text editor or what ever ... String node?

Comment: @vklidu have to sleep on that one... being a bit dim this pm. Maybe our quellenform will come up with something :)