# How to select specific faces to extrude with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make an object like the one below, which I have managed to create using two different Extrude Mesh nodes, and then combined with Join Geometry.

My concern with this method, more than just being inelegant, is that there will be overlapping geometry from the two joined objects.

Is there a way to do this with a single Extrude Mesh node, somehow giving the selection the specific indices to extrude without having to use an "equal to" or "greater than" range?

[image]

NOTE: I have seen this question asked in other forms, but the other questions are not specific to my needs. In particular I would like to know if it is possible to give the Selection input of the Extrude Mesh node specific indices (i.e. 1, 2, 5, etc), as opposed to a math range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use multiple extrusion nodes, you can consolidate your index `Compare` selections with `Boolean Math` nodes. For the specific example you provided you would use one in *Or* mode, and it would look like this:

[image]

You can learn about the modes [in the manual here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/boolean_math.html). Unfortunately, there is not an option to enter a list of index numbers to select them at once, however. So if you have many indices you wanna add into a `Boolean Math` setup, it can get a bit long winded an tedious. Depending on the task at hand, you might wanna use other comparison methods, like direction, in that case.

Comment: thank you so much for chiming in with this answer.  Every time I post to this forum I keep my fingers crossed for a few names in particular and yours is one of them.  I have not been made acquainted with the Boolean Math Node yet, and I just felt a leap of evolution in my understanding of making selections in geonodes.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's kind of you, thanks. I recently had [a level up moment regarding how selection works](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281245/attribute-as-selection#comment483315_281245) myself, so I know the feeling :)